# How to add MWPhotoBrowser project referance in my own iphone image gallery apps?

Tags: iphone, xcode, macos

I want to make an iphone app like the native iphone photo gallery....i found a project MWPhotoBrowser and now i want to use some feature of this project....but i don't know how to do this....i am new in iphone apps development..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The github page worked great for me. They have a great tutorial. Here is the link: https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Answer (score 5):

First, you have to import in your project the "framework" you had downloaded. Then, you have to make a class "viewController" (the .h and .m files) and set the view like this:
.h should be like this

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MWPhotoBrowser.h"

@interface PhotoLoader : UIViewController<MWPhotoBrowserDelegate> {
    NSArray *_photos;
    UISegmentedControl *_segmentedControl;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *photos;
@end
```

the file. m shoud be like this

```
//  PhotoLoader.m


#import "PhotoLoader.h"

@interface PhotoLoader ()

@end

@implementation PhotoLoader
@synthesize photos = _photos;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Create browser
    MWPhotoBrowser *browser = [[MWPhotoBrowser alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
    browser.displayActionButton = YES;

    //show your photo whit url

    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://Url.Photo.Here.jpg"]]];
    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://http://Url.Photo.Here.jpg"]]];
    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://http://Url.Photo.Here.jpg"]]];
    [photos addObject:[MWPhoto photoWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://http://Url.Photo.Here.jpg"]]];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
- (NSUInteger)numberOfPhotosInPhotoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser {
    return _photos.count;
}
- (MWPhoto *)photoBrowser:(MWPhotoBrowser *)photoBrowser photoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    if (index < _photos.count)
        return [_photos objectAtIndex:index];
    return nil;
}
- (void)segmentChange {
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

@end
```

That's all.

Comment: Hello Mamunur. Please consider to set the checkmark at the answer if this is the right answer. This will help follow up readers.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer there [Github](https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser)
and also have look at [DOC](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=14XR5zcZb2Kz2s6A4AbzB00NLkrW9bWxMMprVsUao-hY).
This might be helpful.
There are other [Lib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13269740/which-one-is-a-better-ios-photo-viewer-three20-or-egophotoviewer) which can also help.
All of them are following same steps of zooming, scrolling, cache, etc.