# Which one is a better iOS Photo Viewer: Three20 or EGOPhotoViewer

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, uiimageview, three20

I am making an app for showing an image gallery in iOS, and I came across two samples.

I want to know the differences between [Three20](https://github.com/enormego/three20) and [EGOPhotoViewer](https://github.com/enormego/PhotoViewer). I mean both apps are developed by same developer ([enormego](https://github.com/enormego)).

- Is it safe to use them for the app store, I mean it may not get rejected, and compatibility with iOS6?
- Is there any advantage of using EGOPhotoViewer over Three20?
- Is it worth to stick to Three20 for any important feature of cache, thread, etc.
- In code both almost use the same classes and function with different names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would recommend against Three20 for 1 reason and 1 reason only: Three20 code is a bit messy and generally there are a lot of interdependencies with other Three20 classes, ones you might not need. It's sucks to include the whole Three20 library in your project just to use the photo browser. I'd like to keep things as simple as possible.

I've used the EGOPhotoViewer one in the past and while it generally worked fine, I did have some minor issues with it, which I sadly can't remember. Eventually I found a replacement in MWPhotoBrowser, so you might consider that one as well.

https://github.com/mwaterfall/MWPhotoBrowser

Comment: Thanks @Wolfgang for quick reply, I also started using EGOPhotoViewer as Three20 was quite complex. I will consider that MWPhotoBrowser also. Please try to share the issues you got using that. Thanks. :)

Comment: +1 for MWPhotoBrowser, used it in the past and loved it

Comment: I think my main issue was customising EGOPhotoViewController. There also might have been an issue with orientation switching, you might test that out (perhaps it's fixed by now, I haven't used it in several months).

Comment: @jere Thanks for sharing your experience.

Comment: @WolfgangSchreurs ,yes orientation not working, will try to fix it or will go for MWPhotoBrowser. :)

Comment: I came across a new 
[FGallery](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone). It is very Lite and working fine on iOS5, But when I run it on iOS6 orientation is not supported. I alos tried 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(6_0);
Can anyone help?

Comment: This[Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12519693/unable-to-handle-orientation-in-ios-6) helped. [FGallery](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone) is working fine. :)
Thanks!!

Comment: Great response, thanks! @Wolfgang I have customized EGOPhotoViewController in the past and it required lots of refactoring. The package works great but the code is Spaghetti, even doing the simplest modification requires you to look inside and fix things. It's not great code. As for Three20, that library should be avoided like the plague - I think it was created by Facebook for the first iteration of their app; now Facebook doesn't use it anymore. There is a reason. Thanks for the other tips I'll check those.

Comment: MWPhotoBrowser is no longer maintained and has dependencies that are no longer maintained.